# how to access the daily usage hours a person spends on social media like instagram,whatsapp,linkedin,facebook

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to access the daily usage hours a person spends on social media like instagram,whatsapp,linkedin,facebook. I want to update the data at end of the day to show stats about how much social media a person is using on daily basis.I want the data in the web app. Is this possible and if possible then how to get this data

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO;

Answer (score 0):

The answer is: Not possible in a browser since you cannot have one web app monitor other web page interactions. You would have to make a desktop program that hooked into the network connection.

Alternatively you might get some APIs like

- https://developers.facebook.com/
- https://www.whatsapp.com/business/api/?lang=fb

to give you usage stats